# Finding a specific sum of elements from two arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm, search, binary

Could you please help me with this one? :
"Let A and B are an incrementally ordered arrays of natural numbers and K be some arbitrary natural number. Find an effective algorithm which determines all possible pairs of indexes (i,j) such that A[i]+B[j]=K. Prove algorithm's correctness and estimate its complexity."

Should I just iterate over the first array and do a binary search on the other one?
Thanks :)

Comment: I would say so. Iterate over the smaller array and do a binary search over the larger one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No!

Both arrays are ordered, so you do the following:

- Place an iterator `itA` on the beginning of `A`
- Place an iterator `itB` on the end of `B`
- Move iterators in opposite directions, testing `*itA + *itB` at each iteration. If the value is equal to `K`, return both indexes. If the value is smaller than `K`, increment `itA`. Else, decrement `itB`.

When you go through both arrays, you are done, in linear time.

Answer (score 1):

Since, for every A[i] there can only be one B[j], you can find the solution with O(n+m) complexity. You can rely on the fact that, if (A[i1] B[j1]) and (A[i2] B[i2]) are both correct pairs, and i1 is less than i2 then j1 must be greater than j2. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps, it's just an idea. Loop A linearly and binary search B, but do A backwards. This might give you a better best case, by being able to exclude some portion of B at each step in A.

If you know that A[i] needed say B[42] to solve for K, you'll know that A[i-1] will need at least B[43] or higher.

EDIT: I would also like to add that if B has fewer elements than A, turn it around and do B linearly instead.

Answer (score 0):

Possible implementation in C++ can look as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int A[]={1,2,3,6,7,8,9};
    int B[]={0,2,4,5,6,7,8,12};

    int K=9;
    int sizeB=sizeof B/sizeof(int);
    int sizeA=sizeof A/sizeof(int);


    int i=0;
    int j=sizeB-1;
    while(i<sizeA && j>=0)
    {
        if ((A[i]+B[j])==K){
            std::cout << i<<","<<j<< std::endl;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
        else if((A[i]+B[j])<K){
            i++;
        }
        else{
            j--;
        }
    } 
    return 0;
}
```